# Alter elements of generic collection property in a subclass child collection

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, collections

I have a simple interface ElementContainer (which is also an element) which holds a list with Elements in it:

```
interface IElementContainer : IElement 
{
    List<Element> Elements { get; }
}
```

Now I have a class implementing this interface:

```
class ConcreteContainer : IElementContainer
{
    List<IElement> Elements { get; private set; }
}
```

But I don't want the class to be a container for all Elements but only for a subset of them, say SpecificElement, however this is not possible (ofcourse):

```
class SpecificElementContainer : IElementContainer
{
    List<SpecificElement> Elements { get; private set; }
}
```

Therefore I thought of something like:

```
class SpecificElementContainer : IElementContainer
{
    List<IElement> Elements { get; private set; }
    List<SpecificElement> SpecificElements
    {
       get 
       {
          return return Elements.FindAll(el => el is T).Select<IElement, T>(el => (T)el).ToList<T>();
       }
 }
```

But this way I can not do something like: `SpecificContainer.SpecificElements.Add(...)` since it not added to the Elements. And besides that... it smells fishy to do it like this.

Any clues how to restructure this in a sane way?

***Edit after Jon Skeet's answer***

Reading Jons comment my problem is actually a little more complicated than I showed above but I forgot some very important information.

When I have a class which implements the above interface and the elements list is filled like this:

```
Elements = { ConcreteElementA, ConcreteElementA, ConcreteElementC, ConcreteElementB }
```

What I would like is that I could do this `ConcreteContainer.ConcreteElementCs.Add(new ConcreteElementC())` which would result in:

```
Elements = { ConcreteElementA, ConcreteElementA, ConcreteElementC, ConcreteElementB, ConcreteElementC }
```

**Additional edit**

After some confusion I want to rephrase my question as follows:
I have a collection `List<Element> OriginalCollection`. I want to create a subset collection with elements which implement Element, ConcreteElement, `List<ConcreteElement> Subset` and add to that in such a way that `OriginalCollection` is also modified.

Comment: Advice - use same code convention, as used everywhere in .NET, i.e. interfaces named with prefix `I`: `IElement`

Comment: Thanks, I will remember; My above post is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @avanwieringen: Yes, but when you're trying to illustrate something, it's still important to be clear...

Comment: You're right, I have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `ElementContainer` interface should be generic:

```
interface ElementContainer<T> : Element where T : Element
{
    List<T> Elements { get; }
}
```

Then:

```
class SpecificElementContainer : ElementContainer<SpecificElement>
{
    List<SpecificElement> Elements { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with a more complex problem, which is actually the problem I am meant, but failed to illustrate properly :)

Comment: @avanwieringen: You're still not illustrating it clearly, I'm afraid - I don't understand your update. If `ConcreteElementCs` is always just a copy, then you simply can't add to it (and expect anything useful to happen) - you would need to add to `Elements` instead. Why would you not just do that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I am thankful for your help. Is there any way to retrieve a subset of a collection, add to that in such a way that the original collection is modified?

I am afraid it is not possible and I will have to refactor my code using the solution you provided, which is actually a lot more sane then the thing I am trying to create I think.

Comment: @avanwieringen: I think you'd have to write your own collection to support that. It's feasible, but difficult in various ways.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Thanks! I will rethink my architecture.